# create properties with their values dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

i have an object with a property with the names of the properties i want to create in the same object with a certain value . i can do it the old way but i thought a simple fat arrow solution should be avaible. And that i don,t have to use the array arr object but directly the caps value of device . arrow functions dont have a this referring to itself anymore. How to get a way the brackets in the cap value array ?

```
let arr = ["onoff", "alarm_motion", "alarm_night"]
let fillcap = arr => {

    let obj = {}

    arr.forEach(a => {
        return obj[a] = false
    })
    return obj
}


let device = {
    caps: arr,
    cap: arr.map(c => ({ [c]: false }))
}


 device = { caps: ['onoff', 'alarm_motion', 'alarm_night'],
 cap:
 [{ onoff: false },
 { alarm_motion: false },
 { alarm_night: false }]
 }
device = {
    caps: arr,
    cap: fillcap(arr)
}

device = {
    caps: ['onoff', 'alarm_motion', 'alarm_night'],
    cap: { onoff: false, alarm_motion: false, alarm_night: false }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do won't work, but you can do something like this:

```
const arr = ['onoff', 'alarm_motion', 'alarm_night'];

const device = {
    caps: arr,
    fillcap() {
        this.cap = this.caps.reduce((cap, c) => Object.assign(cap, { [c]: false }), {});
    },
};

device.fillcap();
```

Comment: map gives brackets around the key value pairs making it objects that is what i want to  avoid, the bracketts

Comment: I've modified the answer, @wetlip